# "Connect to Server" does not save the username and password

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, sftp

I use the `Files (nautilus)` utility to connect to my server. Every time, I set to remember my username and password forever, but next time it asks for the username and password again.[image]

Comment: The image you attached is not opening, would you try it again?

Comment: @LuisMilanese what do you mean by not opening? I uploaded via askubuntu.com interface. I checked it in another browser, and it is working.

Comment: I also have this problem with 16.04 (though I usually use Nemo). It seems to be a more general problem with the Gnome keyring, because I get the same behaviour with Enigmail asking for my passphrase in Thunderbird. For me this has only started happening in the last couple of months though. My system is an upgrade from 14.04.

Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @Moilleadóir no luck yet. It's still painfull.